# Do you need to mash out?

Tags: all-grain, mash

I have just finished my second all grain brew.  I failed to mash out and went straight from the mash to boil.  What difference will this make to my beer?

Comment: Welcome to Homebrewing John. The question you asked has been asked and answered more than once before; similar questions should have popped as you were writing yours. BTW the short answer is, it will be just slightly lighter in body, but not enough to notice.

Comment: @Pepi, thank you.  I am new to the forum(and to all grain - although I have been brewing since 1981).  I will need to lean how to search for questions before asking them and taking people's time unnecessarily.